# How to attach the file

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP.Net, VB.Net

In my web page, i want to attach the file.

How to attach the file

Need code help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anishmarokey might be referring to the [FileUpload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `asp upload` control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

Comment: Look at the code sample in the link he provided.  This shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `input` tag in HTML with `type=file` to create file upload object with a text box and Browse button.

For Ex. `<input type="file">`

More information at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263%28VS.85%29.aspx)